# Extract data from txt corpus to .csv in R

Tags: r, rstudio, export-to-csv, tm

I looked through the board but could find no answer to my problem within R studio.

So maybe anyone has the time and kindness, to help me.

I have a folder containing 106 txt files and I wish to extract data.

As a result I want to build a .csv with two rows. First row shall contain the file name, second row shall contain a number, whis is the last "word" of the first line.

Those first lines of each document look like "Document x of y". The second row shall therefore contain y. Please note, that x may contain one, two or three digits.
If this is not possible I would be really happy, if the .csv could contain the whole first line in row 2.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does involve a lot of steps, so I think it deserves an answer, but I'd like you to try and refine your question a bit more to make sure that I'm answering what you intend to ask. For example, you say you want a csv with two *rows*, but from the sound of your description I think you actually mean that you want two *columns*. I've made some guesses about this in the solution below.

There's a few basic steps happening here:

- iterating through your working directory to find paths and names of .txt files
- reading all the lines from each file, one at a time
- selecting the first line
- breaking the first line into words
- selecting the last word of the first line
- appending that word to a running list
- and after the iteration is complete, building a data.frame and writing to a csv output

```r
fp = tools::list_files_with_exts(dir='.', ext='txt', full.names = TRUE)
fn = tools::list_files_with_exts(dir='.', ext='txt', full.names = FALSE)
fn = tools::file_path_sans_ext(fn)

items = length(fp) # get our iterator length for files

lastword = as.character(NULL)
for(i in 1:items) {  # iterate through files
  line = readLines(fp[i])[1]  # read in lines and select the first
  words = strsplit(line, ' ')[[1]]  # split string into vector on spaces
  word = tail(words, 1)  # get the last word of the vector
  lastword = c(lastword, word)  # combine with lastword list
}
df = data.frame(filename=fn, lastword)
write.csv(df, 'my.csv')
```

Comment: Wow @Mikuana thank you so much. I am not good at coding, but if I read your suggestion I get what your solution is and I like it.

I really mean columns. Sorry for the confusion!

If I try your code though, the following error occurs: 

`Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory`

I tried to google it, and moved the file to another folder as well and used `setwd`. It seems to be an R specific error and I have no idea how to workaround :(

Comment: Sorry, me again, I forgot to mention that I also made sure that my source path ends with a "/" as discussed in another Stackoverflow thread.

Comment: I think both errors are there because `fp == NA`. Have you looked at the elements of the `fp` object? Are you getting back a vector of what look like valid file paths to your txt files?

Comment: Thank you! If I type `fp` the reply is `character (0)`. As far as I understand, this means that there is no valid path. I guess this is unlikely, but do I maybe lack of some packages? I made sure to enter the directory path correctly by entering it with the assistant "dialogue" within R Studio. Also, the directory path does not include any other characters than usual english letters.

Comment: It may also be an issue of permissions. What environment are you developing in? Does the R session that you're running have the appropriate priviliges?

Comment: Also, ensure that you're using the right directory. Type `getwd()` inside of R to see what directory you're pointing at when you execute this code.

Comment: Thank you again! `getwd()` proved that I am using the right directory. I am running R Studio with Administrator rights and it is installed onto my system partition. Conducting a different analysis I was able to use `docs <- Corpus(DirSource("D:/Dokumente/Dropbox/Dropbox/BrexitDiskursanalyse/Korpus/Guardian/"))` in order to establish a corpus and subsequently a document term matrix. So apparently the program is able to use the source .txt-files.

Comment: Okay so it looks like you're using Windows (based on your file path). My testing is on Linux, so perhaps there are some differences in using `'.'` to resolve the relative path? Maybe try `list_files_with_exts(dir=getwd(), ...)` instead of using a dot. I apologize for the uncertain suggestions; I'm just making some guesses at this point.

Comment: Yep, I am using Windows. Really should have mentioned this before, sorry. I tried to vary between `"`and `'`. Also I made sure that the path is resolved with the same interpunctuation than in the above mentioned file where I was able to set the source. Using `getwd`within a `list_files_with_exts`command didn't work. It is just a pity, I wonder what the problem is. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Maybe I should start another issue?

Comment: Probably not a bad idea. If you figure it out, I'd be happy to update my answer with whatever solution actually works. Just give me a mention here.

Comment: Okay, thank you anyway for your time and kind effort!